# Will using the Code first approach and Entity framework be able to make my asp.net mvc web application works on any database vendors

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008-r2, code-first

I usually use database first appraoch to develop my asp.net mvc web application and then i map the database tables using entity framework,,, but this apprahc will make my web application works only under specific DB vender .

so if i use the code first approach and entity framework and i do all the buisness logic on the application layer (for example i do not use any  stored procedures); **will my application in this case works fine regardless of the database vendor ???**
BR

Comment: you mean the engine (sql server, oracle, mysql, etc.) or the schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For EF to work on other rdbms requires"drivers"to be written to support the platform. MS only supports MSSQL. I know there are oracle libraries for EF, but I don't know about any others.

That said, the only way to make sure your application is portable is to develop against all the libraries you hope to support and constantly test against all of them during development. Otherwise it's just a pipe dream.

Of course, you can do the same thing with  ADO.NET using ANSI SQL.